# Circular Dependency Error for Google Guice with Play2.4 and scala

Tags: scala, guice, playframework-2.4

My application uses **Play 2.4 with Scala 2.11** .I started transforming my existing code to make use of **Google Guice** that comes with Play 2.4 .

When I run my code after making the first set of changes , I found Some DAOs in my code are failing with **circular dependency error.**

For example I have two DAOs

```
class BookDAO @Inject()
(protected val personDAO : PersonDAO,
 @NamedDatabase("mysql")protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
...
...
val personId = //some id
personDAO.get(personId)
}

class PersonDAO @Inject()
(protected val bookDAO : BookDAO,
 @NamedDatabase("mysql")protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
...
...
val bookName= //some id
personDAO.getByName(bookName)
}
```

I got the below error while trying to access either BookDAO or PersonDAO

```
Tried proxying schema.BookDAO to support a circular dependency, but it is not an interface.
  at schema.BookDAO.class(Books.scala:52)
  while locating schema.BookDAO
```

Can someone help me resolving this error .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your dependencies as follows and pull up all needed methods from class to trait:

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[BookDao])
trait IBookDao {
  // abstract defs
}

class BookDao @Inject()(protected val personDAO: IPersonDao, protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] with IBookDao {
}

@ImplementedBy(classOf[PersonDao])
trait IPersonDao {
  // abstract defs
}

class PersonDao @Inject()(protected val bookDAO: IBookDao, protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] with IPersonDao {
}
```

As you can see, each `dao` implements a trait and all `dao` dependencies are injected by `trait`. This gives `Guice` possibility to inject a proxy class and resolve a circular dependency issue.

More details on `playframework scala` dependency injection [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).

Answer (score 4):

### Quick solution

Inject a `Provider` instead:

```
class BookDAO @Inject()(personDaoProvider: Provider[PersonDAO], ...)
extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  val personDAO = personDaoProvider.get
  def person = personDAO.get(personId)
}
```

And the same for `BookDAO`. This will work out of the box. Guice already "knows" how to inject Providers.

---

### Better approach

Decouple the class definition from the implementation. See Mon Calamari's answer.